# Get the id before the current one

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I have the following code to have as a result the id previous to the current one, I do not use any calculation such as adding one or subtracting one because sometimes I have skipped ids, for example, from 1 to 3 and from 3 to 4, can you think of any solution? Thanks for your time

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE temporada=$idTemporada AND id<$id";
        $res3 = mysqli_query($conn,  $sql3);
        $ant_cap = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res3);

        echo $ant_cap['id'];
```

if my current id is 5 and the previous database id is 3 then the result of the echo of $ant_cap['id'] is 3

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE temporada=$idTemporada AND id<$id";
        $res3 = mysqli_query($conn,  $sql3);
        $ant_cap = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res3);

        echo $ant_cap['id'];
```

Comment: Why did you post the same code twice?

Comment: I may probably not understand your question in the same context, but wouldn't be easier to create a new column that you can use for this purpose and that new column could continuously be incremented by 1? This way you don't rely on the id, in case it is automatically incremented by a count that is not adequate for your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX(id)` to get the highest ID below the current one.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT MAX(id) as previous_id
    FROM videos
    WHERE temporada = ? AND id < ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $idTemporada, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$res3 = $stmt->get_result();
$ant_cap = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res3);
echo $ant_cap['previous_id'];
```